# How detailed should be the employment certificate?

Tags: manager, germany, employer, recommendation-letter

I want to ask my former employer to issue a letter of Employment Certificate for me so that I can give it to my next employer (in Germany). Besides the employment period and my position title there, what other information should be included in the letter?

For instance, any assessment of my performance or the type of projects I was working on?

Generally, should it be like a recommendation letter or only a confirmation of my previous employment?

Comment: I'm not from Germany but in general it depends on what your previous employer wants to provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted from [here](https://www.employmentlawworldview.com/the-german-arbeitszeugnis-reference-a-sometimes-dangerous-mystery-for-non-german-employers/)

> Every employee in Germany is entitled to a written reference called the “Arbeitszeugnis” (Section 109 German Industrial Code – “GewO”). An employee may seek a “plain” reference or a “qualified” reference.
>
> A plain reference merely indicates the nature and duration of the employment relationship, while a qualified reference also describes and evaluates the employee’s conduct and performance during the employment relationship. In practice all employees expect and demand a qualified reference.

So, what seems to be, you'd need to ask for a "qualified reference" which shall contain your performance level and your behavioral history, besides the employment period and my position title there,

Comment: Good to know that. I can give my employer a general draft to prepare the letter. Should I also include the project titles there?

Comment: @Babak I don;t think mentioning project name/title is a good idea (or even allowed). It's about your association with the organization and the performance, not about the individual projects. Mentioning technology and domain are acceptable, not the exact project name / title.

Answer (score 1):

> Besides the employment period and my position title there, what other information should be included in the letter?

Some employers ask for salary information to be included in the employment certificate (I know this practice varies greatly from country to country though).

> Generally, should it be like a recommendation letter or only a confirmation of my previous employment?

No. It should not be a recommendation letter. If they want a reference letter, that should be handled separately and usually an individual like your supervisor would provide that and will not be a formal company document.  (Pretty much every company I worked for consider their appraisals of the employee strictly internal and do not share it outside).

Comment: Then how can it assess the employee’s behavior or performance?

Comment: @Babak It doesn't.  For a new company to assess performance of an employee from past company, most common way is to get a reference from previous manager.   This is different from "Employment Certificate"

Comment: As this is tagged Germany, your answer seems to be wrong. Do you have any experience getting or reading a German "Arbeitszeugnis"?